# iTunes review URL not working in iOS9?

Tags: ios

I've been using this URL successfully on iOS 8 to direct users to my app rating URL, but it stops working on iOS 9

```
"itms-apps://itunes.apple.com/WebObjects/MZStore.woa/wa/viewContentsUserReviews?id=984230464&onlyLatestVersion=true&pageNumber=0&sortOrdering=1&type=Black+Mouton"
```

I'm getting the error message: 
Your request produced an error. [newNullResponse]

Any solution?

Answer (score 2):

This is working on iOS 9:

```
NSString *reviewURL = @"itms-apps://itunes.apple.com/WebObjects/MZStore.woa/wa/viewContentsUserReviews?id=<#YOUR_APP_ID_HERE#>&onlyLatestVersion=true&pageNumber=0&sortOrdering=1&type=Purple+Software";
```

Comment: Out of curiosity, what is the `type=Purple+Software` referring to?